# Is it possible to reach 800 deg Celsius on copper?

Tags: resistors, heat, thermal

I want to heat a copper bar of 2 x 2 x 1 cm to 800 degrees Celsius. I think it is possible by Kanthal, Nichrome wires. If so, what is the required length, diameter and power? I want to make this heater a very small one.

Comment: Probably no one here knows the answer.  Many of us can figure it out.  But why should we?  Why should anyone bust their rear end to help out someone who obviously has NOT made any attempts to figure this out for themselves.

Comment: If *YOU* put some effort into this *and* show the work that you have done, someone here should be able to guide you when you get stuck.  But *YOU* have to put in the effort.

Comment: is "cmm" a new ...flexible unit?

Comment: @GR Tech : Centi-millimetre. 1 cmm = 10 microns.

Comment: it doesn't take any power to heat the bar, it takes energy to heat the bar,  it takes power to counter the unspecified environmental losses, it seems pretty tiny: can't you just zap it with a laser or something.

Comment: @BrianDrummond...really? in what official system?

Answer (score 1):

Because you have only written a partial question with partial research (well none shown) and partial effort (again none shown), I will write a partial answer.

First you need to know how much energy you need to put into the block. There is an equation for that:

$$Q = C_p \times m \times \Delta T\space\space\space\space \mathrm{[Joules]}\space\space\space\space  (1)$$

Lets review what those variables are. \$C_p\$ is the specific thermal capacity of the material, \$m\$ is the mass, and \$\Delta T\$ is the temperature rise required. All of these are in SI units.

The mass can be calculated from the density of the material:

$$m = \rho V\space\space\space\space(2)$$

Where \$\rho\$ is the density, and \$V\$ is the volume. Again, in SI units. I think the volume you should know how to calculate.

Now for copper, \$\rho\$ is `I'm totally tired of searching it`\$^*\$. So doing Equation (2) with your dimensions gives a mass of approximately `I couldn't be bothered to calculate it`\$^*\$.

You want to heat the block up to \$800^\circ C\$. Lets say you start at room temperature of about \$23^\circ C\$. That gives you \$\Delta T = 777^\circ C\$ (I'll give you that one for free). So we are most of the way there. There is one more thing we need to find out, so we can look up on the internet and find that for copper, \$C_p\$ is `I'm totally tired of searching that too`\$^*\$.

So putting all of the numbers in to Equation (1) we calculate that it takes `Insert value here` Joules of energy to heat the block up assuming no losses.

But that isn't enough to answer your question. It just tells you how much energy you need to put into the block to heat it to the required temperature.

---

Now that is as far as I go because there are some critical pieces of information missing. How fast do you want to heat the block? Energy is all well and good, but to work out how powerful the heater needs to be, you need to convert the energy into Power, which requires knowing time (Power is Energy per unit Time). You also have to factor in losses - how fast is energy (heat) being lost to the surroundings? If you insulate the block and heater it will take far less time to heat up for a given power as there is less energy being lost. Basically:

$$P_{in} = \left(Q + E_{loss}\right) / t$$

---

\$^*\$ Actually I did get all the values and do the calculations, but I'll let you do the work.